# How do I easily convert and send PDFs to a Nook GlowLight or SimpleTouch's native format

Tags: epub, conversion, pdf, nook

Amazon makes it easy to convert PDFs and send to Kindle in the Kindle's native format. How to do this (simply!) on a Nook?

I do know conversion is possible with tools such as Calibre but I was wondering if there is a way that is comparably simple to the Kindle's method of emailing the PDF to a conversion service.

The goal: In 3 steps or less, with an existing PDF from a computer, convert to the Nook native ePub format and appear on my e-Ink Nook device.

Comment: I assume connecting the Nook via USB cable isn't an option here? Also, I thought PDF and ePub were two separate formats? Are you asking about converting between the two or ?

Comment: Connecting via USB cable is fine - though obviously that adds an extra step. I long ago abandoned using a Nook to read a PDF-converted-to-ePub as there were too many steps (compared with Kindle which is trivial). If it can be reduced to 2-3 steps (with plugging in USB cable as one step) that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried using Amazon to convert the PDF to MOBI, and then use a MOBI2EPUB convertor?

Comment: I guess your goal is to obtain an epub version that is readable on your nook. First point: a PDF file can be a collection of scanned pages - essentially a number of large images. Converting that to epub just gives you an epub file with those images. Not so readable. Assuming your PDF file has text, you can convert it - there are websites that take a PDF and return epub; there are commercial products that do it. I use Calibre to do this exact thing. The big caveat here is the readability of the epub file will depend on the source PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You could just plug it in with USB and move the PDF file, which is compatible with NOOK readers.

Comment: That takes care of the transfer but not the conversion to the Nook's native format. Reading a PDF formatted file on an E-ink device is generally pretty terrible, and that includes Nook. So I was wanting to know if it's possible to do something that is as simple (or nearly as simple) as sending A PDF to Kindle while also automatically converting to Kindle format. For Kindle, all that is needed is to send an attached PDF to your Kindle email address with "convert" as subject.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a rooted Nook, you can always install Dropbox on it, so you can use its syncing feature.

Comment: This won't convert the PDF to Amazon's native e-book format.

Comment: That's totally irellevant for the original question @NathanOsman as it was about reading and syncing docs on/to a Nook *like* Amazon allows it.